# Use local NTP service

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I'm trying to get a system with no outside internet access (A) to get the time from another system on the LAN that does (B).

In A's ntp.conf (the whole thing is at bottom), I've added:

```
server 192.168.2.102
restrict 192.168.2.102
```

Referring to B's IP. After an hour of reading man pages, looking at online examples, etc., as far as I can tell this should mean it will use that local server, and trust it for anything.

However, it doesn't work.  I can watch the two exchange times in `wireshark`, and running `ntpq -p` on A shows:

```
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
192.168.2.102   .INIT.      16 u   16   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

If I stop `ntpd` on A and try `ntpd -gq`, I can again watch a back and forth in wireshark, but after a minute or two the command times out with "No servers found".

I've even tried adding to A's conf:

```
fudge 192.168.2.102 stratum 1
```

Doesn't make any difference.

**How can I force ntpd to set the time from a specific server?**  It looks like this used to be easy enough using `ntpdate` -- which is depreciated and does not exist on the system.

---

Here's the entire ntp.conf for machine A.  This is stock Debian wheezy.  The only changes I made were to add the lines involving 192.168.2.102, and comment out the debian pool servers to try and eliminate confusion there, so they are unreachable anyway.

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable


# You do need to talk to an NTP server or two (or three).
#server ntp.your-provider.example
server 192.168.2.102
restrict 192.168.2.102
fudge 192.168.2.102 stratum 1

# pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
# pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
# pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
#server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
#server 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
#server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
#server 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst


# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient
```

Comment: Is the ntp server on B definitely working, and allows other clients on the same LAN to connect successfully (testing with `ntpdate` on another system maybe, it's still in Debian/Ubuntu/Mint)?

Comment: Like I said, they exchange messages with timestamps in them (wireshark breaks down the protocol).  So they both work and communicate back and forth.

Comment: How about test with `sntp -d (A)`? Anything else that might give some more useful error messages. The "No servers found" message implies something's up with the server.

Comment: @Xen2050 `sntp` works and did lead me to a solution -- although machine B synced itself, it reports otherwise (`ntpq -p -crv` shows no starred server and `sync_unspec`).  Adding a fudged `127.127` entry to machine B fixed that, and now A accepts it. O_o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did get it working, so for posterity, someone on `#ntp` (freenode) said machine A may not be happy if B does not report itself as synced.  This can be observed with `ntpq -p` on B not showing any servers prefixed with an asterisk.

Fudging a local source on **B** (which actually does sync, by examination of the system clock) corrected that:

```
server 127.127.1.0
fudge  127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```

However, it's important to *not* do that on **A** since it will trust stratum 10 more than whatever it counts the "locally synced" machine B as.

Comment: This exact issue was bugging me for months. This exact solution was the only one that worked for me. Haven't seen it anywhere else on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

Something like the following should work.

```
restrict default ignore
restrict 127.0.0.1 nomodify

restrict 192.168.2.102 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap noquery
server 192.168.2.102 burst iburst

server 127.127.1.0
fudge  127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```

Comment: **Why** would that work?  It doesn't look any different than what I already have, beyond the fact that the loopback is listed.  I'm not saying you are wrong, but I don't want to start randomly cut n' pasting/cargo culting a config someone else cut n' paste/cargo culted.  There's hundreds of these online already.

Comment: I actually just took it from a working example (from my work, not online) of what you're wanting to do. I don't actually know what this has in it that you might be missing.

Comment: Okay, I did try replacing my whole conf with this.  The only difference it makes is `LOCAL` is now listed with `ntpq -p`.

Comment: +1 Because this did help me toward a solution.  However, I had to get rid of the last two lines since `stratum 10` for the local server still seems to have taken priority from machine B when unfudged.

Comment: `burst` and `iburst` are mutually exclusive. Pick one or the other. In general `iburst` is preferred for public servers but if this is a local server you can use `burst`